# RSS App which shows article

Tags: android, wordpress, rss

I saw many tutorials how to build an RSS reader in Android, but I need a RSS reader which doesn't open the browser with the article, I need one which shows the article in the app. And only the article, nothing else. Any help / ideas?

Comment: use a webview to display the content.

Comment: how canbi done it to inly show the content? that is my problem i don't know how to show only the content.

Comment: I don't know what to try. What can I try?

Comment: usually, one starts by downloading the rss feed, then parse it, then display it in a basic fashion, then enhance the look. how far are you ?

Comment: Oh ok. I downloaded the feed and I can show it. I have only one problem, and this problem is that when i click on one article in the feed then it opens the browser and shows the hole website. But i only want to show the content. Nothing else.

Comment: depends. if the feed contains the article, you can display it. if it contains only a link, that's different. can you post the feed url ?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own RSS parser based on XML parser. Try use library org.simpleframework.xml as XML-parser: http://simple.sourceforge.net/